# I cant find the View Editor in the CouchBase Web Console

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I've just installed couchbase, however on the web console i cannot find the view editor mentioned in this post (http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-edito...)

In the link above, it says " clicking the Create Development View button within the Views section of the Web Console" but my web console does not have that button. I am using the "Version: 1.8.1 community edition (build-937)" and it looks like this

[image: screenshot of my couchbase web console].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase 1.8.x does not contain view support. You will need to use version 2.0 if you want this feature.